# Performance: imap_headers() or imap_fetchheader()?

Tags: php, imap, gmail-imap

I've got a need to download all the headers in a mailbox (body will not be needed). A mailbox may well have 100k messages or more.

imap_headers() promises to return all the headers for a mailbox; which would make things simple to use. I have concerns though of whether this is going to be performant across the range of IMAP servers out there (and some not giving all the headers).

The alternative is to use imap_search() to get a list of IDs and then imap_fetchheader() to iterate through and get all the headers (likely using some sort of queue system).

Has anyone come across this issue? If imap_headers "works" reliably (or there is an easy way to tell that it failed) then that would be preferable; otherwise I think imap_fetchheader is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Neither of these will work well under all circumstances. Asking for message headers of *all* messages in a mailbox which contains several thousands or maybe hundred thousands od messages is a wrong idea. On the other hand, processing them one-by-one is not sane, either, as the library which you're using is synchronous, and hence you'll be limited by round trip times between the host running your PHP script and the IMAP server you're querying.

Get an asynchronous IMAP library and use some reasonably sized window/range of messages to fetch. E.g. retrieving a couple dozens or a couple hundreds messages each time is probably reasonable.